# Combinations of multiple product sets with different quantities

Tags: combinatorics

Given we have 3 sets of products: `candies`, `chocolates`, `nuts`. The items/products within the same set are all the same.

Where:

- `candies` quantity = 30 items
- `chocolates` quantity = 5 items
- `nuts` quantity = 6 items

A customer can add to the cart only as many items as there are available.

How to calculate the number of distinct carts a customer can create? i.e. all the different combinations of carts for these products and their quantities? The order of items in the cart does not matter, but quantities of each item do.

Example:

- Cart combination A: `candies` Q = 1, `chocolates` Q = 3, `nuts` Q = 2;
- Cart combination B: `candies` Q = 2, `chocolates` Q = 3, `nuts` Q = 2;
- Cart combination C: `candies` Q = 3, `chocolates` Q = 3, `nuts` Q = 2;

My assumption would be to multiply each product sets quantities:

```
30 * 5 * 6
```

Would it be a correct approach for the problem?

Comment: If there is only 1 item available for each product, what would be the answer?

Comment: To emphasize Vasily's hint, you might consider the possibility of having gotten *none* of one or more of the types.  This begs the question also of... do you still consider someone who bought nothing at all a "customer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are in correct way ,but there is something you ignoring .It is the case that we do not have to take an element from each types.So , you must add $+1$ to the number of each product , it will represent "nothing" ,i.e $0$ element from that type. So , the answer is $(30+1) \times (5+1) \times (6+1) =1302$ if the empty cart is allowed , if the empty cart is not allowed , then subtract $1$ from the answer , the subtracting $1$ represent the empty cart case ,i.e (nothing from the candies ) $\times$(nothing from the chocolate) $\times$ (nothing from the nuts) = $1 \times 1 \times 1 =1$ , so $1302-1 =1301$

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation! That makes sense. I knew I was missing something. That was indeed +1 for not picked products. Empty cart is not a combination in this case, therefore -1 from the total result.

Comment: @Edgar you are welcome , i glad to help you..